# AutoMapper mapping based on containing property name

Tags: automapper

Is it possible mapping two classes based on their similar property names:

```
class Source {
  public int uId { get; set; }
  public string PrefixRef { get; set; }
  ...
}

class Destination {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Prefix { get; set; }
  ...
}
```

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

-1, smart alek.
I'm totally new to AutoMapper.

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {
  cfg.RecognizePrefixes(new[] { "u" });
  cfg.RecognizePostfixes(new[] { "Ref" });
  cfg.CreateMap<Source, Destination>();
});
```

Comment: See the AutoMapper Wiki for the option to [replace characters](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Configuration#replacing-characters) in the mapping of fieldnames or to remove standard [prefixes](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Configuration#recognizing-prepostfixes).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is working with prefix and suffix settings.